# CDH4 JAVA_HOME Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop

I have installed CDH4 in pseudo distributed mode on CentOs without any problems, but when I am installing it on Ubuntu 12.04 I am getting some errors with setting my JAVA_HOME environment variable.

I installed JDK and and have JAVA_HOME set correctly in `/etc/profile.d` and in `~/bash.rc` using the following lines:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/latest
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
```

I know that is redundant to define it in both places, but apparently setting it in `/etc/profile.d` wasn't working. From my user, when I type `$echo $JAVA_HOME` I get:

```
/usr/local/java/latest
```

From sudo, I run `$ sudo -E echo $JAVA_HOME`, I get:

```
/usr/local/java/latest
```

If you are wondering, I am specifying the -E option for sudo to preserver my environment.

So my real problem is when I am trying to start HDFS, using the following command:

```
for x in `cd /etc/init.d ; ls hadoop-hdfs-*` ; do sudo service $x start ; done
```

I get the following error:

```
* Starting Hadoop datanode: 
Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found.
```

Running the same command with the -E option gives me the same result. Has anyone had this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

After some research, I found the answer to my question.

I am using CDH4 and have hadoop installed in pseudo-distributed mode.

To fix my JAVA_HOME problems, I created a the `hadoop-env.sh` file in `/etc/hadoop/conf.pseudo.mr1`

The file contained the line:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/latest
```

Where /usr/local/java/latest is the path to my installation of JAVA_HOME